# If my validator needs to call the database before validation, should I just let the database handle this validation?

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, validation, database-design

Given the following contrived and trivial database schemas:

```
Owner
|id|name|age|

Car
|id|owner_id|model|color|

owner_id references Owner(id)
```

In my SpringBoot application, if I want to insert a new `Car` record, there are two ways to prevent passing a non-existent `owner_id`.

1. Wrap the insert statement in a try/catch block to catch Springs `DataIntegrityViolationException`

```
try {
  jooq.insertInto(CAR)
  ....
} catch (DataIntegrityViolationException ex) {
  ....
}
```

2. Use a validator in the service/controller layer. This validator would need to query the database anyway

```
class CarValidator {
  OwnerRepository ownerRepository;
  
  public boolean ownerIdExists(UUID ownerId) {
    Set<UUID> ownerIds = ownerRepository.fetchAllOwnerIds();
    return ownerIds.contains(ownerId);
  }
}
```

I prefer the latter (2) but sometimes I feel it's redundant given you need to go to the database anyway. The former feels like you end up clogging almost all your insert statements with try/catch blocks.

Given these two examples which is better and why?
If you think there's a better way to handle this, please add it in your answer.
If this has been answered somewhere please point me to it.

Comment: The second one has a TOCTTOU problem. Guess what happens if between the check a record is inserted with the same ID: you're check won't detect it, and you end up with the first option anyway. Not to mention that retrieving all IDs will become slower and slower and more memory intensive as your database grows.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with approach 1. It will save me time for an extra app server to db roundtrip.

I assume you are using JPA/Hibernate with JDBC connection pool. In approach two, you will have one single connection as both db queries will be part of same session. But on that same connection you will do two round trips, one for select & one for insert. And I am assuming from the above scenario, chances of user not present is a failure scenario which will happen very few times. So essentially, you are saving time all most all the cases.

Regarding try/catch on all the inserts, I think you have one or at most two(ideally only one as I don't see any point why you would need more) insert statement to car & that can be encapsulated within a method. You can handle all the database constraint errors within this single DAO method, and throw javax.validation.ValidationException exception from there. Your service class methods can work on the javax.validation.ValidationException exception & you don't need to handle any JDBC/database specific error in service layer.